# Tex Utility breaks after upgrading to Tex Live 2015

Tags: texlive, mactex

OS: Mac OS X 10.10.3

I had Basic Mac Tex Live 2014 before. I upgraded to Mac Tex Live 2015 and then uninstall Tex Live 2014 by removing the folder `/usr/local/texlive/2014basic`.

After the upgrade, I found the installed packages missing when compiling the tex file. I checked in the Tex Live Utility and found some additional packages are `Not Installed` (i.e. the packages that are not distributed with basicTex).

When I tried to install the packages, an error popped out:

```
The repository at http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
has TeX Live 2015, but you have TeX Live 18446744073709551615 installed.
You need to switch repositories in order to continue.
```

I wonder where the version `18446744073709551615` come from. In the configuration of distribution, it is shown that `TeXLive-2015-Basic` is installed.

---

#### EDIT

Sorry about not searching carefully. I found the cause and a workaround at the GitHub of Tex Live Utility: [Issue 17](https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/issues/17).

The issue seems to be due to the distribution of Mac TeX Live.

Comment: Your Edit should be an answer. (You can answer your own question.)

Comment: Also answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250181/mactex-tex-live-utility-broken-after-2015-update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found other people come across the same problem and find the workaround via my question. So I undelete the question.

Please refer to Issues page of TeX Live Utility: [here](https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/issues/17) for the cause and workaround.

It seems that a new release of MacTeX Live 2015 has fixed the problem.