# MacTeX - TeX Live Utility broken after 2015 update

Tags: mactex, updating

I have the following strange message.

```
The repository at ftp://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet 
has TeX Live 2015, but you have TeX Live 18446744073709551615 
installed. You need to switch repositories in order to continue.
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Perhaps the oleane.net repository is not yet updated to TL2015. The message says that you have to use another mirror. I had the same problem with my default mirror under TL2015 (Linux) and switching to another mirror (and some wait delay) solved the problem

Comment: That is not what is saying in the message. It seems that I have a corrupted number for version. Am I right ?

Comment: I can't check that. I don't use MacTeX

Comment: Install the new MacTeX

Comment: I've done it just now and I have this message.

Comment: I am cleaning all my TeX folders and reinstalling MacTeX. Then I will be back to keep or not this post opened.

Comment: @projetmbc It'd be more useful if you posted your solution as an answer for future visitors that might have your problem. Also, I'd enter the message as text in your question so that it can be searched. Images cannot be searched with text. :)

Comment: Quoting the Tex on MacOSX Mailing list: “The version of TeX Live 2015 that was originally released in MacTeX-2015 is missing a file needed by TeX Live Utility so an updated version should be released in another day;” http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.macosx/47095

Comment: @FranckPastor -- please post an answer.  other questions are coming in about the same problem, and although they are pointed here in comments, it's not possible to close them as duplicates until the question being pointed to has an answer.

Comment: https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/issues/17

Comment: @Barbarabeeton Done!

Comment: Maybe it would be better to add the text of the error message as actual text here, so people can find it by searching the internet. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250188/35864

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to write to Herb for a fix. Credit goes to Bruno Voisin for finding the solution to this. Some background is here:

https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/issues/17#issuecomment-111517743

I think the simplest solution is here, requiring use of the Terminal:

http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2015-June/036927.html

```
cd /tmp

curl 'https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/release-texlive.txt?revision=36787&view=co' > release-texlive.txt

sudo cp release-texlive.txt /usr/local/texlive/2015
```

Each of those three commands should be on a single line; the second is wrapped on this page. An updated version of MacTeX should be making its way around the CTAN mirrors right now.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting the Tex on MacOSX Mailing list:

> The version of TeX Live 2015 that was originally released in
>   MacTeX-2015 is missing a file needed by TeX Live Utility so an updated
>   version should be released in another day;

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.macosx/47095

Answer (score 1):

This post [Fresh install of MacTex on El Capitan, Tex Live version shown as 0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272084/fresh-install-of-mactex-on-el-capitan-tex-live-version-shown-as-0) led me to this note from [Adam Maxwell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/61839/adam-maxwell) which worked for me:

Please try the latest beta; there's a path issue with El Capitan that would cause a misleading error message. https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/releases

Answer (score 0):

It is amazing how this is still broken.

I just removed mactex 2015 and installed mactex 2016.

Tex live utility is still broken.

However, I just downloaded the latest tex live utility from their own development page. It does work.

Go to mactex homepage, go to tex live utility homepage, download, unpack and overwrite tex live utility. Then start it and it works.

Comment: If you think TeX Live Utility is broken, please file a [bug report](https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/issues). If you can describe the problem and include enough information for me to reproduce it, I'll try to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250903/mactex-2015-tex-live-utility-stuck-on-validating-server?rq=1 Hi Adam! This is what still happens. However I downloaded the latest tex live utility from their development page and it did not get stuck. The one that comes with Mactex 2016 does get stuck on 'validating server' like the one that came with Mactex 2015 did. I have latest OS X in Macbook Pro 15.

Comment: That bug was fixed a year ago, and the same problem does not apply. Please file a bug report or email it to tlu@tug.org (no need to subscribe to the mailing list). I need to see the log output from when it gets stuck (use the Windows menu) in order to understand what's going on.

Comment: Yes, but why they still ship the broken version with the mactex.pkg?

Comment: The version shipped with TL 2016 does not have this bug. Period. If you were using the version from TL 2015, it would exhibit the problem you saw.