# Can not update packages in Tex Live Utility after installing Tex Live 2015

Tags: packages, tex-core, mac, repositories

since Tex Live 2015 was released these days, I updated it. I´m using a Mac.

Now I wanted to check for package updates in the Tex Live Utility. But that does not work, unfortunately.
First strange thing is that I have to choose the repository address by hand. Normally, this worked automatically. But even if I do so and choose an address, Tex Live Utility would show the following error message:

*"The repository at http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet has TeX Live 2015, but you have TeX Live 18446744073709551615 installed.  You need to switch repositories in order to continue."*

And there is also an error message regarding an "internal error".

Does anyone know what I have to do to get this working again? I guess it has something to do with updating to Tex Live 2015?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250181/mactex-tex-live-utility-broken-after-2015-update ;-)

Comment: Did you install MacTeX 2015?

Comment: MacTeX 2015 is installed. Even the new version that the article above refers to.

Comment: EDIT:

Just read that a hopefully working version will be released no earlier than June, 18th. I was confused because I installed one version yesterday, uninstalled it and a few minutes ago installed a version released today. I thought that was the final version already.
But it really seems to be a missing package. So i might just have to wait for the upcoming distribution. :D

Thanks anyways.