# MacTeX 2015: TeX Live Utility stuck on "Validating Server..."

Tags: mactex

After having upgraded to MacTeX 2015, whenever I run TeX Live Utility, it stays stuck with the "Validating Server..." message.

[image]

Clicking the "Home" button causes it to crash.

However, `tlmgr update --all` from the terminal works fine, so I don't think it's about some mirrors not carrying TeX Live 2015 yet.

Has anyone else encountered this problem with TeX Live Utility, or is it specific to my installation?  Is there a known fix for the problem?

This is TeX Live Utility version 1.21.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you need to update the Tex Live Utility itself first. What happens if you do `tlmgr update --self` and then try it within GUI?

Comment: @Pouya There are no updates available either for `tlmgr` or for the TeX Live Utility GUI program.

Comment: insert the repository url `ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/`. Does it change the behaviour?

Comment: @Herbert It crashes, but before it does, it now shows a message saying that this URL has TeX Live version 2015 while I have TeX Live version 18446744073709551615.  That can't be right! :-)  Do you know how TeX Live Utility determines the TeX Live version?  https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ar8ysll635x3jg/Screenshot%202015-06-18%2010.38.39.png?dl=0

Comment: Does this help: http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2015-June/036927.html

Comment: There has been a bug in mactex due to a missing file `release-texlive.txt`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250181/mactex-tex-live-utility-broken-after-2015-update.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer and Herbert Thanks for the help, please mark as duplicate.