# Fresh install of MacTex on El Capitan, Tex Live version shown as 0

Tags: installing, mactex, updating, repositories

On a fresh install of El Capitan and MacTex, I'm getting this error message while the texlive utility is checking for updates:

```
The repository at http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/systems/texlive
/tlnet/ has TeX Live 2015, but you have TeX Live 0 installed.
You need to switch repositories in order to continue.
```

I tried [this fix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250181/mactex-tex-live-utility-broken-after-2015-update) but nothing happened. Can anyone offer some input on this?

Comment: I would suggest reinstalling MacTex again. I'm running El Capitan here, and I've had no issues.

Comment: Did you install MacTex after upgrading to El Captian? I already tried reinstalling, but didn't remove all the ghost scripts.

Comment: *Nothing* happened? You got no output at all from `curl`?

Comment: Please try the latest beta; there's a path issue with El Capitan that would cause a misleading error message.  https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/releases

Comment: @cfr - Of course curl downloaded a text file and put it into /usr/local/texlive/2015, containing a version. By nothing happened I meant there was no behavior change.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell Thanks for pointing me to the beta. I ran it and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Please file a bug report and include all of the log output from TLU (see the Window menu). https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/issues

Comment: For what it's worth, the previous beta didn't work properly if you had the multiplexor set as your repository. You might try the latest one (currently 1.22b8) before bothering with a bug report.

Comment: 1.22b8 worked! Thanks @AdamMaxwell. Please write an answer so I can select it for everyone who's having the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El Capitan removes the long-time MacTeX default path location of `/usr/texbin` and does not allow it to be recreated. Various parts of TeX Live Utility assumed this as a default path setting. Unfortunately, under some conditions you could also end up with this error message instead of the intended message (because Apple only displays the first alert sheet on a window).

A partial fix is to change your "TeX Programs" setting in TeX Live Utility's Preferences window; if you have MacTeX 2015 or BasicTeX 2015, you can use `/Library/TeX/texbin` as the new location. If you have an older TeX Live, you will need to navigate to the correct binary directory containing the `tlmgr` tool (e.g., `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin`). See TeX Live Utility's **Help** menu for details on this setting.

A more complete fix, including better warning messages, is available in the latest beta and soon-to-be released version of TeX Live Utility. The latest beta release is available here:

https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/releases

The built-in Sparkle updater should notify you when the final version is released, hopefully in the upcoming week. If you encounter problems with the beta, use the **Problems or Questions** from the **Help** menu to file a bug report.